# Get Distinct characters from a given string in sql server

Tags: sql-server, string, function, t-sql

i need a T-SQL function that remove duplicate charcters in a give String

for exemple Fn_Remove('AVGHAHA') 
it will returns AVGH

Comment: You might have to write a UDF to handle this.  I'm not sure that anything in SQL Server out of the box would help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack overflow isn't a website for stating what you "need" it's for asking coding questions. Do you want to treat upper case and lower case characters separately?

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738165/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-string-in-sql

Comment: `A` is also a repeating character, why is it not removed from your example ?

Comment: I believe by "duplicates" they mean "the 2nd, or more occurrence of the character" @GuidoG. Notice that the first `A` is present (at the start of the string), as is the first `H` (in position 4), any latter occurrences of the character do not.

Comment: yeah that what i meant by repeating 
i tried many functions but they do not work and i'm new in sql server to be honest

Answer (score 2):

Using [`NGrams8K`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/), you can split the string into individual character "tokens", apply a number to that character set, and then rebuild with only the first of each character:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.S,
           N.position,
           N.token,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY N.token ORDER BY N.position) AS RN
    FROM (VALUES('AVGHAHA'))V(S)
         CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(V.S,1) N)
SELECT V.S,
       (SELECT '' + C.token
        FROM CTE C
        WHERE C.S = V.S
          AND C.RN = 1
        ORDER BY C.position
        FOR XML PATH('')) AS Replaced
FROM (VALUES('AVGHAHA'))V(S);
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a Numbers table with ascending integers from `1` upwards.

Then you can use

```
SELECT STRING_AGG (Char, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Pos ASC)  AS csv
FROM
(
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, number, 1) AS Char, MIN(number) AS Pos
FROM Nums
WHERE number <= LEN(@String)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(@String, number, 1)
) T
```

This uses the semantics of your default collation for equality. Use an explicit `COLLATE` clause if you want something different.

If you are on a version that does not support `STRING_AGG` you can use `XML PATH` for string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be using recursive `CTE`, which I learned yesterday from one of @Gordon Linoff's answer.

```
;with cte as (
      select v.input, convert(varchar(max), '') as updated, 1 as lev
      from (values ('AVGHAHA')) v(input)
      union all
      select stuff(input, 1, 1, ''),
             (case when charindex(left(input, 1),updated) > 0  then updated  else concat(updated , left(input, 1))  end),               
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where input > ''
     )
select top (1) with ties updated
from cte
order by row_number() over (order by lev desc);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/EFG82968)

**Edit**:

As a user defined function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Fn_Remove(@Input varchar(100))  
RETURNS varchar(100)   
AS   
-- Returns the stock level for the product.  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret varchar(100) 
    ;with cte as (
          select v.input, convert(varchar(max), '') as updated, 1 as lev
          from (values (@Input)) v(input)
          union all
          select stuff(input, 1, 1, ''),
                 (case when charindex(left(input, 1),updated) > 0  then updated  else concat(updated , left(input, 1))  end),               
                 lev + 1
          from cte
          where input > ''
         )
    select top (1)  @ret=updated
    from cte
    order by lev desc

    RETURN @ret;  
END;
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, now i'm struggling to add it to a funcation

Comment: as i said i'm new at this

Comment: @yassinemhadhbi, i have created it as function, you can check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for your help 
but i needed a function 
and i found a solution

```
USE [DATAWARHOUSE]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[EliminateRedoblons]    Script Date: 3/14/2019 1:52:02 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[EliminateRedoblons](@str VARCHAR(500))
  RETURNS varchar(500)
  begin
  DECLARE
          @resultat VARCHAR(500)='',
          @i INT=0,
          @is INT,
          @c NVARCHAR(1)

          while @i<=LEN(@str)
          BEGIN
          SET @i=@i+1
          SET @c=substring(@str,@i,1)
          SET @is =CHARINDEX(@c,@resultat)
          IF @IS=0 
          BEGIN
          SET @resultat=@resultat+@c
          END

          END
          return @resultat


  END
GO
```