# Regex to get only last occurrence of each digit in string

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am working with SQL Server and have come to encounter a situation for which I have no answer. It is as follows:

Given a string `diuuuu`, for example, I would like this output `diu`. The logic behind it is the **last** occurrance of each digit (d, i, u) in order. Other examples:
`diudi` = `udi`
`dididi` = `di`

A Regex solution would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This is looking for the LAST occurrence of each letter.  The Regex logic here would be "ignore all characters where the string has a later character that is the same"

Comment: May be a copy of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160719/get-distinct-characters-from-a-given-string-in-sql-server

Comment: No.  That's T-SQL and not Regex, and it gets the first character.

Comment: ... SQL Server *uses* T-sQL @MPost , and SQL Server does *not* natively support REGEX.

Comment: This post is a little confusing, as the main question references SQL Server but the title references Regex.  Not sure which is being asked for here.

Comment: Likely because the OP *thinks* they need Regex to get the result, @MPost , however, (as I mentioned) SQL Server doesn't natively support Regex. That isn't to say that can't use it, however, they would need to implement a CLR function, so any answer would need to include details of how to create one with the required functionality and enable the instance to make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't particularly pretty, but it does do the job:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('diudi'),('diuuuu'),('dididi'),('ddddd'))V(YourColumn)),
Ranks AS(
    SELECT V.YourColumn,
           CI.C,
           CI.I,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY V.YourColumn ORDER BY CI.I) AS R
    FROM VTE V
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REVERSE(V.YourColumn)))R(YourColumn)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES('d',CHARINDEX('d',R.YourColumn)),
                            ('i',CHARINDEX('i',R.YourColumn)),
                            ('u',CHARINDEX('u',R.YourColumn)))CI(C,I))
SELECT YourColumn,
       REVERSE(CONCAT(MAX(CASE WHEN R = 1 AND I > 0 THEN C END),MAX(CASE WHEN R = 2 AND I > 0 THEN C END),MAX(CASE WHEN R = 3 AND I > 0 THEN C END)))
FROM Ranks
GROUP BY YourColumn;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 (.)(?!.*\1)
```

The groups returned, concatenated together, give you what you want.

Comment: How will the OP use that in SQL Server?

Comment: The request ended:  "A Regex solution would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"  Maybe a CLR DLL is being developed.

Comment: I would have expected the question to have been tagged with C# then, as the OP should have included the existing code for their CLR function.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a SQL Answer:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_LastChars(@str VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @result VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @char CHAR(1)
  DECLARE @i INT = 1
  WHILE (@i <= LEN(@str))
  BEGIN
    
    SET @char = SUBSTRING(@str, @i, 1)
    SET @result = CONCAT(REPLACE(@result, @char, ''), @char)
    SET @i = @i + 1
  END

  RETURN @result
END
```

Comment: Yes, I could make this more efficient, but it's easy to use and understand.